# Dynamic property getters/setters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Storage (localStorage, sessionStorage) allows using arbitrary properties. E.g. you can do

```
localStorage.foo = 'bar';
```

instead of

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

Can my own javascript objects have the same behavior? I want to execute some code, when a property is attempted to be set.

**Note**: I obviously know I can create setters, but that won't work for properties whose names I don't know in advance.

**Note #2**: After a bit of examination of the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface), I see that it doesn't really guarantee that this will work, unless the key was already set with setItem():

> The names of the supported named properties on a Storage object are the keys of each key/value pair currently present in the list associated with the object

I could probably achieve this behavior myself too, as long as the first set goes through a method, by dynamically defining getters/setters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`__defineGetter__()`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) and [`__defineSetter__()`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineSetter), but unfortunately they're Mozilla extension to Javascript 1.5, so they're only available in some browsers (recent versions of Firefox, Opera and Safari).

[More information and some examples here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/).

Other than this, there is no way to add custom behaviour to setting/getting properties on an object.

Comment: There's also new ECMAScript 5 getters and setters, currently making their way into new browsers.